# Unterschied zwischen rufen und anrufen?

Tags: verb, vocabulary, separable-verb

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „rufen“ und „anrufen“?

Both *rufen* and *anrufen* mean to call, so what is the difference between the two apart from anrufen being a trennbar verb?

Comment: There's a big difference, you probably didn't catch all available translations well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main difference is, that *Anrufen* always needs another person/object.

Most people will use the verb *anrufen*, in the meaning of to give somebody a call (via telephone), while *rufen* is used for calling or shouting in general.

Anrufen can be used when you are shouting at someone like in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anrufen)'s example

> der Wachposten rief ihn an

in the meaning, that a guard shouts at someone (to get his/her attention).

or when you are asking for help, most likely a deity

> Gott um Hilfe anrufen

---

*Rufen* on the other Hand doesn't need another person. It can be just an action

> In den Wald hineinrufen
>
> Ich rufe nach Hilfe

Answer (score 1):

*Rufen* is a mode of using your voice, louder than speaking and often "sung", with a drop of a minor third between syllables ("[Rufterz](https://www.srf.ch/audio/100-sekunden-wissen/rufterz?id=10535549)"). As such, the verb can be used intransitively; but it can also have different types of objects.

> 1. Die Kinder riefen laut. (*intransitive*)
> 2. Das Publikum rief seinen Namen. (*transitive*)
> 3. Der Nachbar rief die Polizei. (*transitive*)
> 4. Man rief nach einem Arzt. (*with prepositional object*)

In 2., the accusative denotes what is being shouted; in 3., it specifies who is being called and asked to approach. With a prepositional object as in 4., the verb has the meaning of requesting, demanding. It can also be used figuratively: *Viele riefen nach strengeren Kontrollen*. (The difference between 3. and 4. might not be obivous at first: 3. requires an actual call to be made, 4. could involve shouting in the air or discussing a course of action.)

*Anrufen* means contacting someone and is therefore "semantically transitive". Currently, this mostly refers to phone calls (but it can still refer to contacting gods and asking them for help: *die Götter anrufen*). Note that the accusative object is often omitted: *Da hat wieder jemand angerufen.*